# .NET Core - XElement could not be found when targeting .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: .net-core, xelement

I'm having a weird problem when using XElement in .NET Core project und targeting .NET Framework 4.6. I've made a very simple project to reproduce the error.

1. I create a standard library project with only one class.

   ```
   public class Class1
   {
       public Class1()
       {
           XElement element = null;
       }
   }
   ```
2. And in my project.json, I would like to target .net core and .net framework 4.6

   ```
    {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",

      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
       "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.3.0"
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {
          "imports": "dnxcore50"
        },
        "net46": {
        }
      }
    }
   ```

When I compile the project, I always receive the error "*The type or namespace name 'XElement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*" (this error happens only with .NET Framework 4.6)

I have no idea why it doesn't compile. I've tried to create a Console Application with .net framework 4.6 and add reference to System.Xml.XmlDocument and it works. Only with .NET core project, it doesn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. System.Xml.Linq has to be added as frameworkAssemblies for net46

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.3.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "net46": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Xml.Linq": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```